# AngularJS - Creating a directive that is the opposite of ng-required

Tags: validation, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that will add attributes based on the results of an expression. I created a directive called `blank` that ensures that a field is empty. I only want this directive to be in affect if the results of boolean expression is true.

In affect, I want a directive like `ng-required` that adds `required` based on a condition. I can't find any code that shows how to evaluate an expression on the right side of an attribute.

Comment: Without some example code it is hard to fully understand.  But you can eval any expression with `$eval(exp)` on a scope.  Docs for `$eval`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$eval

Comment: I would suggest looking at the code base for ngRequire

Comment: create a demo with what you are attempting.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne Could you help me in locating it? I downloaded the source code but cannot locate anything but spec and documentation.

Comment: @TravisParks https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1283

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, it is very easy to create custom validation in AngularJS based on an attribute. AngularJS doesn't care what a validation is named. If you call `$SetValidity` at the right times, everything works like it should.

@kevin-stone's answer is going in the right direction. After I was able to accurately formulate my question, I quickly found this blog entry that sums up how to create an attribute that adds new validation: https://medium.com/acekia-startup/48d9e823e17e.

This is a bit of a complex example. In short, create a directive, `restrict`-ed to attributes (`A`) and `require` `ngModel`. Then `$watch` or `$observe` the attribute in the element. You can then look at the current model value and set the validity by calling `ngModel.$SetValidity`. Again, AngularJS doesn't care what you name your validation (in my case "blank").

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `attrs.$observe` to put a watch on the value of an attribute.

```
module.directive('yourDirective', function() {

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        attrs.$observe('yourDirective', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            // Add or change attributes or classes here based on `newVal`
        });
    }

}]
```

See [documentation for Attributes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile.directive.Attributes) for more information.